# Improve DELETE query Oracle

Tags: oracle, plsql

I have a query to delete some records from a table, but take too much time.
The table is use it in a stored procedure to match another table.

Every time that the SP is executed the table is truncated and filled with 2 or 3 millions of records depending of the received parameters.

The table doesn't have any FK or constraints

The query to delete the records that I am using is:

```
DELETE FROM TABLE1
WHERE (fecha,hora_ini,origen,destino,tipo,valor,rowsm1) IN (
    SELECT fecha_t,hora_t,origen_t,destino_t,tipo,valor,id_t
    FROM TABLE2)
```

I try to decrease the time in execute the query creating an index based in the same columns of the query

```
CREATE INDEX smb1 ON table1 (fecha,hora_ini,origen,destino,tipo,valor,rowsm1);
```

And the query take more time to execute.

How can improve the performance of this "DELETE" query.

**UPDATE**

EXPLAIN PLAN OUTPUT

```
DELETE  TABLE1 

TABLE ACCESS TABLE1

TABLE ACCESS FULL TABLE1  

TABLE ACCESS FULL TABLE2

TABLE ACCESS FULL TABLE2
```

Comment: what does the explain plan say?

Comment: I don't understand what you mean. I need to delete the records from the TABLE1 based on the records in the TABLE2., but take too much time

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28274/ex_plan.htm#i3305

Comment: How many rows are there in TABLE2?

Answer (score 0):

The index you created looks like a quite big index:

```
CREATE INDEX smb1 
    ON table1 (fecha,hora_ini,origen,destino,tipo,valor,rowsm1);
```

Sure, this depends on the amount of data but generally I would rather look for one or two [selective columns](http://www.akadia.com/services/ora_index_selectivity.htm) - if possible.

Don't forget, that the index data has to be read as well and if it doesn't help to speed up the query, you even loose performance.

This might for instance happen, if the table is very small, because the database reads data block by block (I think it was about 8K). A small table can be read in one step - no need to use an index here.

Or, if more or less all records are selected. In this case the table has to be read anyway.

If you want to speed up the query you should create the same index (with a good selectivity) on `table2`. This way the `EXPLAIN PLAN` will look somewhat lie this:

```
DELETE   STATEMENT                  
DELETE      
NESTED   LOOPS SEMI
INDEX    FULL  SCAN
INDEX    RANGE SCAN
```

Answer (score -1):

You can switch off logging and delete the rows,

Here is an example, you can do it 2 ways,

1.) Physically chaning the table to Nologging

2.) Using Nologging hint in the delete statement.

1.) First approach

both testemp and testemp2 are same tables with same data while testemp takes over a minute , testemp2 takes only 1 second

```
SQL> delete from testemp;

14336 rows deleted.

Elapsed: 00:01:04.12
SQL>
SQL>
SQL> alter table testemp2 nologging;

Table altered.

Elapsed: 00:00:02.86
SQL>
SQL> delete from testemp2;

14336 rows deleted.

Elapsed: 00:00:01.26
SQL>
```

The table needs to be put back to logging only when we physically change the table using "Alter" command, if you are using as hint not required please see the example below

2.)   Second approach

```
SQL> set timing on;
SQL> delete  from testemp2;

14336 rows deleted.

Elapsed: 00:00:01.51

Deleting data after reinserting same data into table now with nologging;



SQL> delete /*+NOLOGGING*/ from testemp2;

14336 rows deleted.
Elapsed: 00:00:00.28

SQL> select logging from user_Tables where table_name='TESTEMP2';

LOG
---
YES
```

Comment: `DELETE` and `UPDATE` always generate REDO and UNDO.  There is no `NOLOGGING` hint, it is only an option used to create and alter tables.  The time difference in the example is probably from caching.

Comment: @JonHeller, ok, if not the hint, then atleast in the first case, where iam physically changing the table to nologging, testemp and testemp2 are differnt tables, in that case the time is reduced, i dont think caching would come into picture there , would it ?

Comment: No, but the test case currently isn't fully reproducible so it's hard to know for sure.  Also, take a look at [this part of the manual](http://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/clauses005.htm#SQLRF52284) that discuss what operations support `NOLOGGING` mode.